# Organizing two columns in descending order for SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've found code that should work, I am trying to organize data in descending order, however, when I put in this code, I only get the first one in descending order, not both.  I want both in descending order, how can I do that?  Here is my code. The overall goal of this is to make sure that NumberOfPlays and FourthDownConversions are in descending order by Formation. Can someone help here?

```
SELECT Form, Down/Dist as AverageDistance, Play/Down AS NumberOfPlays, Gain/Down AS FourthDownConversionRate
FROM footballOffStats
WHERE Form IS NOT NULL AND Down = 4 AND Form != "" AND Gain IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FourthDownConversionRate DESC, NumberOfPlays DESC;
```

These are the results being produced, how can I get NumberOfPlays and FourthDownConversion both in descending order?

```
Form    AverageDistance NumberOfPlays   FourthDownConversionRate
EARLY LT    4   109.25  1.25
DIAMOND 2   34.25   0
DBL FLEX    0.4444  24.5    4.25
SHIFT TO EMPTY  0.4 24  5
BLUE LIZ    0.8 23.75   1
BLUE RIP    0.5 23.75   1
BLUE RIP    0.5 23.5    2.25
DBL FLEX SNUG   1   23.25   0
RIP HIP 1.3333  23  5.75
Ace 0.5714  22.5    8.75
ACE RT  0.5714  22.5    3.75
ACE 0.4 22.5    1.75
Early Rip   0.6667  22.5    1.75
QUAD FLEX   0.8 22.5    1.25
ACE 0.8 22.5    1.25
BLUE RIP    0.3077  22.5    0
BLUE RIP    0.4 22.5    0
ACE 0.4 22.5    0
EARLY RIP   1.3333  22.5    0
SEATTLE 1.3333  22.5    0
BLUE RIP    0.5 22.5    0
BLUE LIZ    0.5714  22.5    -1.25
ACE 2   22  3.25
BLUE RIP    1   22  0
Blue Rex    4   22  0
BLUE RIP    0.4 21  13
BLUE RIP    0.16    21  0
EARLY RT    0.4 20.25   9.25
Rip Weak    0.25    20.25   9
Ace 0.4 20  10.75
JUMBO   2   19.5    0.5
HURRY   4   19.5    0.5
TOWERS  4   19.25   0.5
JUMBO   2   19  0.25
BIG GREEN   4   19  0
Blue Liz    0.5714  18.75   10.25
Liz Hip 0.8 18.75   4
DIAMOND 4   18.75   0
Blue LIz    0.2857  18.75   0
DIAMOND 1   18.5    3
WHACKY  4   18.25   12.25
WHACKY  4   18.25   0.75
BIG GREEN   4   18  0.5
BLUE    0.6667  17  -1
BIG GREEN   4   15  0
EMPTY LT    0.8 14  2
ACE 1.3333  14  1
TRIPS LT FLEX   1.3333  14  0
DBL FLEX    1.3333  13.75   1.5
DBL FLEX    0.4 13.25   2.75
DBL FLEX    1.3333  13  1.25
ACE 4   10.5    -0.5
BLUE LT 1   9.25    1.25
BLUE LIZ    1.3333  9.25    0.75
LEX 4   9.25    0
BLUE SEATTLE    2   9   1.5
REX 1.3333  9   0.75
EARLY RT    4   8.75    1.25
REX 4   8.75    0.5
BLUE RIP    0.2353  8.5 2.75
BLUE REX    4   8.5 0.75
BLUE REX    4   8.5 0
JUMBO WING  2   2   1.5
Ace Lt  2   0.5 0.75
JUMBO   4   0.5 0.5
LIZ WK  4   0   17.5
Blue Liz    1.3333  0   9.25
WHACKY  4   0   4.5
HURRY BG    4   0   4.25
ACE LT  4   0   2.25
TRIPS FLEX  0.5714  0   2
BROWN LT    0.8 0   1.5
ORANGE REX  4   0   1.5
BLUE RIP STACK  1.3333  0   1.5
BLUE LIZ    4   0   1.25
BUNCH LT    1   0   1.25
ACE 0.6667  0   1.25
ACE 2   0   1.25
Weak Lex    4   0   1
ACE 4   0   1
DIAMOND 4   0   0.5
Hurry   4   0   0.25
BLUE LT Flop    0.6667  0   0
BLUE BOSTON 0.4 0   0
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You're not making any sense. Your request is illogical

Answer (score 0):

You will only be ordering on column2 if you have 2 or more rows with the same value in column1. its like a backup sort.

Please try explain your issue further and we'll do best we can.

```
SELECT ROWNUM as t2.rn, t2.column1 FROM TABLE1 t2 ORDER BY t2.column1 DESC
FULL OUTER JOIN
SELECT ROWNUM as t1.rn, t1.column2 FROM TABLE1 t1 ORDER BY t1.column2 DESC
ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

The above will likely give u the kind of result you want but you will lose your datas integrity so you might want to rethink. it sounds like youre actually best doing 2 seperate queries, and actually there is no real need to join them.

Comment: I am trying to get NumberOfPlays and FourthDownConversion to be descending at the same time.  Whenever I put in the code in, only the first one with the DESC command gets done.

Comment: see the comment below. a row across ------------- is rigid. i will give u solution in my main answer though

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself and actually, your original answer, IS sorted correctly as required....

Answer (score 0):

you cannot sort both columns data at same time, keep in mind you're sorting records not columns, database will sort records by the first column, an then re-organize data by the second one when the first colum have the same value

So, for example:

```
---------------
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
| 2    | 2    |
| 2    | 3    |
| 3    | 1    |
| 1    | 3    |
```

ordered by col1 and then by col2 both descending will output

```
---------------
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
| 3    | 1    |
| 2    | 3    |
| 2    | 2    |
| 1    | 3    |
```

and never will  output

```
---------------
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
| 3    | 3    |
| 2    | 3    |
| 2    | 2    |
| 1    | 1    |
```

Comment: well, not quite sure what do you want to do, but data must be consistent, that is why you won't get both columns sorted that way, maybe what you need is to use 2 queries to get results sorted by each column, so you can show results in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of your query would be explained if there were a column with the same name in the table.

So, you might try repeating the expression in the `order by`:

```
SELECT Form, Down/Dist as AverageDistance, Play/Down AS NumberOfPlays, Gain/Down AS FourthDownConversionRate
FROM footballOffStats
WHERE Form IS NOT NULL AND Down = 4 AND Form <> '' AND Gain IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Gain/Down DESC, Play/Down DESC;
```